# Fatal Error when pushing visual studio project onto github

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository

I'm trying to upload my Visual Studio 2017 MVC Web App onto GitHub using this tutorial: https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/07/21/step-by-step-working-with-github-repository-and-visual-studio-2015.aspx

I've had success with overcoming any bugs along the way but towards the end on the step where he "commits all", I get the error: **fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output.** I can't think of any reason for this error to be coming up and there's no answers online, the only lead I can come up with is that this web app had a Github repository previously which I deleted.

*Extra Information*: I also have 2 folders that have something to do with this project: 1 is the Visual Studio solution folder and the other is under my Users/Me/source/repos/(empty) folder which never ended up being used and I don't remember why it was supposed to be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to a recently (2 weeks ago, Nov. 2017) fixed bug [reported here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48626/team-explorer-shows-pending-changes-that-have-no-c.html) and [in this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102348/when-commit-i-get-fatal-unexpected-sequence-in-com.html),  for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.1, and fixed in the 15.3 release.

As a workaround, see if a `git commit -m "fixed bug 1"` would work from the command line.

Comment: I'm not exactly confident enough to play with the command line for now but I'll see what I can figure out from your links

Comment: So does this mean I should just update Visual Studio and the issue should be resolved?

Comment: Yes, if you can upgrade to the latest 15.3 release, and see if the issue persists.